# How to run android project cloned from github using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I cloned a project from GitHub using Android studio and I tried to run it, but I get the following error when trying to run it:

[image: picture showing my error]

This should be able to run as I was the one that made it and uploaded it to GitHub. I just couldn't figure out how to use GitHub so I decided to clone the entire project back on my computer and it wouldn't run. It's actually also one of the templates from Android studio.

I tried looking online and I saw posts mentioning options along the lines of "syncing project with gradle", but I can't find that option anywhere in Android studio.

Not sure if this adds more information but in my original project that works and runs, it is able to show the design of the app but in the cloned version it doesn't show any of that, just code.

Answer (score 0):

Resync Gradle is in File->Sync project with Gradle Files.

Has the project been pulled?  Have you checked the project for errors?  Do a build and see what errors there are.

My guess is there is stuff in the project (i.e. libraries) that do not exist anymore in the version of Android Studio you are using. Maybe the project was created with an old version of android studio.  Also, check the Gradle app file and see if there are any problems.

Comment: I'm not seeing the resync gradle option in the file drop down. I have the original file that I pushed to GitHub and I am able to run it on Android studio. I cloned the entire thing onto another directory simply because I'm a beginner to Github and I couldn't figure out how to work with it. It's the same exact version of Android studio on both versions which should be the exact same code anyway, the Android studio version is Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Do clean then build.  you may need to do some code chnages if it was written with an old version.  Android development can be a bit like hiting a moving target.  It can be a little volatile.  Depreciates stuff that stays around for a while but goes originally.